# set of all accumulation points of A is countable

Tags: analysis

How do I approach this question stating: Construct a compact set A of R such that the set of all accumulation points of A is countable.

F compact means closed and bounded. Let $x_k$ element in it. Then since bounded by Bolzano-W it has a convergent subsequence. ??

Comment: Start with the set $A$ with elements $0,1/2,1/3,\ldots$. Then add points so that each element of $A$ becomes an accumulation point of $A$ in an appropriate manner.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit? @DavidMitra

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* What are the accumulation points of the countable set $\{\,a+\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}$?

Comment: @user123 It is $\{a\}$.

Comment: ... and if we call the above set $S(a)$, then what are the accumulation points of $S(1) \cup S(2)$?

Comment: Don't forget that $S(a)$ is not compact though :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the accumulation points of:
$$\{.11,.101,.1001,.10001,\dots,.1\}$$
What about those of:
$$\{.011,.0101,.01001,.010001,\dots,.01\}$$
Or those of:
$$\{.0011,.00101,.001001,.0010001,\dots,.001\}$$
Finally, let's union these all together! We end up with (and you should verify that this actually is the union):
$$\{x\in(0,1):x\text{ has at most two }\\1\text{s in its decimal representation}\}$$
What are *its* accumulation points? (Note: this isn't actually closed yet. You need to add one more element.)

Comment: This is a countable set because it's a subset of $\Bbb Q$. Alternatively, it's not too hard to find a one-to-one correspondence with $\Bbb N$. (The set of accumulation points is countable for much the same reason.)